# Why is the iOS build of a Gluon Mobile app 10 times bigger in size than the same app build for Android?

Tags: android, ios, gluon-mobile

The default single view application build for Android (.apk) takes about 7Mb. The same default application build for iOS (.ipa) takes 38Mb, and after being uploaded to the appstore it takes about 70Mb (due to decompression of .ipa to .app as I understand) - 10 times (!) bigger than the same app for Android.

Is there any way to reduce the size of iOS Gluon Mobile app down to more reasonable values?

Answer (score 0):

It's the virutal machine for running Java on Iphone :)